# compareEntity in Angular not working as expected with select dropdown

Tags: angular

I am using the method compareEntity to compare 2 option objects with ngValue to indicate the selected one. However, the second argument of compareEntity is always an empty string, why?
What am I doing wrong?

I am using angular 12.

The code:
Used to set the selected object:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.audits$ = this.auditService.entities$.pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.entity$),
      map(([audits, entity]) => {
        if (this.formGroup && entity.audit) {
          this.formGroup.value.audit = audits.find((a: Audit) => a.id === entity.audit);
          this.logger.debug(`Setting the initial audit value of audit with id: [${this.formGroup.value.audit?.id}]`);
        }
        return audits;
      })
    );
  }
```

The compare method:

```
  compareEntity(o1: any, o2: any): boolean {
    return o1?.id === o2?.id;
  }
```

And the piece of HTML:

```
    <label for="audit">My label</label>
    <select formControlName="audit" id="audit" [compareWith]="compareEntity">
      <option value="null" disabled selected>Select something</option>
      <option *ngFor="let audit of audits$ | async; trackBy: trackById" [ngValue]="audit">
        {{audit.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you try this.formGroup.get('audit').setValue() method?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to solve it. I am just curious what the difference is between reading the value through "formGroup.value.audits" and formGroup.get('audits').value?

Comment: You can access it both ways. But be careful when using the first one. Because it only returns values of enabled controllers. When you try to get the value of the disabled control, it will be undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've no selected audit in your form, so it compares the options with the currently selected value, in your case null.

So null as o2 is correct.

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ebjfoa?file=src/app/app.component.ts) as a simplified sample of your code where you can see it more easily. Uncomment `this.selectedAudit` in the ngOnInit, and you'll see the results with a predefined audit selection.

If this isn't the full solution, validate if your form is setting your audit correctly on selection

--- edit: ---

Try setting your form with:

```
this.formGroup.patchValue({
    audit: audits.find((a: Audit) => a.id === entity.audit);
})
```

Or as mentioned by Gurkan Yesilyurt

```
this.formGroup.get('audit').setValue(audits.find((a: Audit) => a.id === entity.audit));
```

I've update the stackblitz, if you uncomment line 37: `this.displayAudit(this.auditArray[1]);` this will use a preselected audit. In line 46 you'll see me use patchValue on the form with that audit obj

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?  I do set a selected audit through the code line 'this.formGroup.value.audit=....'.. In your example, you use template form, I use reactive form, it's a bit difficult to compare, can you please change it?

Comment: Updated the answer here, I'll change the stackblitz tomorrow to use reactive forms instead, I made it too hastely, my bad

Comment: updated the answer with a new stackblitz

Comment: Did you update it? I still see the usage of ngModel, not reactive form usage...

Comment: Anyway, I noticed that I am writing the value of a control the wrong way, if I use patchValue it seems to work. But what is the difference between reading the value through "formGroup.value.audits" and formGroup.get('audits').value?

Comment: @edbras yup I changed it to using reactive form, I've made new link try it now? As for your additional question, I don't think there's a difference, they both give you a copied version of the "audit value", you can only change the real value through patchValue or setvalue functions. ```formGroup.value.audits``` was probably implemented later, so they didn't remove the old version, but your IDE will help you prevent spelling mistakes, where a string would not... something similar was done for some NGRX functions